# On form submission the browser loads the php file that had the code for handling the form

Tags: php, forms

I'm writing my first php code... I'm trying to submit a form.
I have two php files. index.php(which contains the form) and process.php(which contains the method that handles the form).
But on form submission, the browser heads to process.php, so nothing is displayed.
I'm trying to echo the result in index.php .

And keep in mind this is my very first php code... :-)

This is index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
  include 'process.php';
  $newletter1 = new newsletter();
?>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address..."><br><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <h4><?php $newletter1 -> abc(); ?></h4>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And this is process.php

```
class newsletter
{

  public function abc()
  {
    if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
      $input = $_POST["email"];
      if (empty($input)) {
        echo "Please provide an email address!";
      }else{
        echo "Thanks for subscribing " . $input;
      }
    }else{
      echo "ELSE is running...";
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: `process.php` is a class definition. That wont run unless you instantiate it somewhere. So you need to change `<form action="process.php"` to `<form action=""` to get it to launch `index.php` which is where you have included `process.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I like your explanation better.

Comment: Thank you very much... It started working. You mean if process.php wasn't a class definition I could write ` <form action="process.php" ` without including it in index.php?? But as it is a class definition I can't make an instance of it in action of course. Right?? :-| @RiggsFolly

Comment: If it was just plain vanilla PHP code, yes

Comment: I got it... I really appreciate your help. :-) @RiggsFolly

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please post an answer for what you wrote. That answer below with them suggesting to change it to "that", is the same thing. The question needs to be marked as solved here and the OP should accept yours.

Comment: @AmirhoseinAl Either Riggs posts an answer or delete the question if you can. The answer given below does not solve your question. I beg to differ on that answer. What's right is right ;-)

Comment: I give up................

Comment: They will all have gone and gotten on with their days @Fred-ii- I posted by the way. Was mid cooking a Curry, sorry!

Comment: @RiggsFolly we try to show people how to write good answers and to explain them, yet still.... I/we often fall onto deaf ears as I have today (not you of course, lol). I obviously haven't gotten my point across in the other answer so I've given up trying to knock some sense into that person. All we can do is "try", yet trying still isn't enough. A great big *SIGH* there. Your continuing contribution on Stack is indeed an asset, remember that. Just don't let it go to your head *lol!!* Cheers buddy. Edit: Curry huh? Yummo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script `process.php` is just a class definition.

A class does nothing unless it is instantiated and a method called.

As you are including it and instantiating it in your `index.php` I would suggest changing your `<form>` tag so it runs itself, leaving `href=""` will do that.

```
<?php
  // run this only if we are being set info by the user
  // so not when the form is first loaded.
  $to_show_later = '';
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
      include 'process.php';
      $newletter1 = new newsletter();
      $to_show_later = $newsletter1->abc();
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address..."><br><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <h4><?php echo $to_show_later; ?></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

It's also bad practice to echo directly out of a class method, so change this so it return the data.

```
class newsletter
{

  public function abc()
  {
    $reply = '';
    if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
      $input = $_POST["email"];
      if (empty($input)) {
        $reply = "Please provide an email address!";
      }else{
        $reply = "Thanks for subscribing " . $input;
      }
    }else{
      $reply = "ELSE is running...";
    }
    return $reply;
  }

}
```

Comment: Now *THIS*, is what we call an "answer", ladies and gents.

Answer (score -2):

In your process.php replace it by:

```
if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
      $input = $_POST["email"];
      if (empty($input)) {
        echo "Please provide an email address!";
      }else{
        echo "Thanks for subscribing " . $input;
      }
    }else{
      echo "ELSE is running...";
    }
```

It will work, and you dont have to include process.php to submit form only

Comment: There's no difference here for what you posted as code and with what the OP's using in the conditionals. Plus, Riggs explained it in comments as to why it wasn't working for them.

Comment: Try and test the code. I removed the class portion. Doing this $_POST was there to serve the posted data. If you have any other explanation you can give @Fred

Comment: that block of code you wrote and stated *"In your process.php replace it by:"* is incorrect. That is the exact code they are using. Only the last part where you state *"It will work, and you dont have to include process.php to submit form only"* is valid here and should have been posted as *"change it to: `<form action="" method="post">`"*. We need to *"dot the i's and cross the t's"* here. This for future readers to the question/answer.

Comment: And what about submitting directly to process.php?